# Rails s won't start on Mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems

`Rails s` gets stuck
I halt it with `cmd+c` and see this error.

I tried to reboot, bundle install, bundle update. I check code is installed an up to date.

what am I missing? : (

thnk you

```
rails s

^CTraceback (most recent call last):
    40: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
    39: from /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
    38: from /Users//.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:37:in `require'
    37: from /Users//.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:37:in `require'
    36: from /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    35: from /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    34: from /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
    33: from /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    32: from /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    31: from /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    30: from /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
    29: from /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
    28: from /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/railties-5.2.8.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:145:in `block in perform'
    27: from /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
    26: from /Users//.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:37:in `require'
    25: from /Users//.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:37:in `require'
    24: from /Users//Library/CloudStorage/Dropbox/Projects//config/application.rb:8:in `<main>'
    23: from /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/bundler-2.4.13/lib/bundler.rb:187:in `require'
    22: from /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/bundler-2.4.13/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `require'
    21: from /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/bundler-2.4.13/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `each'
    20: from /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/bundler-2.4.13/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `block in require'
    19: from /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/bundler-2.4.13/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    18: from /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/bundler-2.4.13/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:60:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    17: from /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
    16: from /Users//.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:37:in `require'
    15: from /Users//.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:37:in `require'
    14: from /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/aws-sdk-s3-1.123.1/lib/aws-sdk-s3.rb:11:in `<main>'
    13: from /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
    12: from /Users//.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:37:in `require'
    11: from /Users//.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:37:in `require'
    10: from /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/aws-sdk-kms-1.66.0/lib/aws-sdk-kms.rb:11:in `<main>'
     9: from /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
     8: from /Users//.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:37:in `require'
     7: from /Users//.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:37:in `require'
     6: from /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.174.0/lib/aws-sdk-core.rb:19:in `<main>'
     5: from /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.174.0/lib/aws-sdk-core.rb:19:in `require_relative'
     4: from /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/iseq.rb:85:in `load_iseq'
     3: from /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/iseq.rb:60:in `fetch'
     2: from /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/iseq.rb:60:in `fetch'
     1: from /Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/iseq.rb:60:in `initialize'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/iseq.rb:60:in `initialize': Interrupt
```

btw

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.7.1p83 (2020-03-31 revision a0c7c23c9c) [x86_64-darwin20]

rails -v
Rails 5.2.8.1
```

Comment: So you say it gets stuck. I assume that means there is no output showing. How long have you waited until you terminated it?

Comment: Does `bundle check` succeed? How about `rails c`? Or `bin/rails c`? You'll need to see if anything works before narrowing down to this specifically.